# Transferring advanced service permission onto copy of a Google Apps Script project

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

I have a Google Sheet that I am using as a template. This sheet contains a script that uses an advanced service. However when I take a copy of the sheet the contained script no longer has permissions to access the advanced service in the dev console (it is "on" in "Advanced Google Service" list).

How can I ensure that the copy of the template sheet also has permission to access the advanced service without having to manually enable it in every copy?

I did find [this way of enabling APIs in the dev console programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854403/is-there-a-way-to-enable-advanced-google-services-in-the-google-developers-conso) from Spencer but I still get the same error about needing to enable the API in the dev console.

I can kind of get it to work by moving the Tasks API functionality into an add-on as it uses the add-ons console project. But that doesn't quite fit with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: why doesn't an Add-on fit your needs? you've tried a library setup?

Comment: There was another SO question about trying a library, but the library was associated with the same project which doesn't have permission. An add-on would do it, but would be difficult to fit into my workflow.

Comment: Is your issue similar to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5314) on the public tracker?

Comment: Yep, +adjuremods that looks like the issue I'm up against. I think I'm going to have to go with creating an add-on.